# How to link wxWidgets in CMake correctly?

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I was trying to make a CMake Projects for the first time with libraries to make a GUI app using wxWidgets.

I have no experience with adding libraries and searching around the internet didn't help me.
I'm on Windows 10 using CLion and CMake 3.21 .

I'm getting some error when I try to include and link wxWidgets to my projects.

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR C:/wxWidgets)
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR}/lib)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)
set(wxWidgets_EXCLUDE_COMMON_LIBRARIES FALSE)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)

add_executable(Project main.cpp)

if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
    include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
    target_link_libraries(Project ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

And my errors:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1053 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/workspace/Cpp/Project/cmake/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


CMake Error at cmake/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1061 (find_package_handle_standard_args):
  Unknown CMake command "find_package_handle_standard_args".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)
```

It looks like I'm missing the `FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake` Script, but I don't know after some research how to get it.

Comment: Does that file exist? It should be looking for (and finding) FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake somewhere other than your project, I would think. I don't use Windows or CLion myself, but could there be a configuration in the IDE somewhere about where CMake should look for its *own* files?

Comment: Because you wrote `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED ...)`, the statement `if(wxWidgets_FOUND)` is always true, so it's useless.